# Codeigniter REST: get request does not work if parameter value contains # symbol

Tags: php, web-services, rest, codeigniter, url

I am using CodeIgniter REST library. 
I am accepting values from the mobile app using get request. After performing operations on that value I m sending response accordingly.
It is working fine.
But if the value in the parameters contains # symbol, I can't get parameters after # and it results in wrong response.

Can anyone guide me in solving this issue?

Below is the code:

```
    public function loginverification_get(){       

    if(isset($_REQUEST['username']))
        $uname=$this->get('username');
    else
        $uname='';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['password']))
        $password=trim($this->get('password'));
    else
        $password='';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['user_type']))   
        $user_type=$this->get('user_type'); 
    else
        $user_type='';


    if(isset($_REQUEST['spiriva_respi']))
        $appcontent=$this->get('spiriva_respi');
    else
        $appcontent='';


    $where='';
    /////////////////
        SOME CODE
    ///////////////////
        if (!empty($user))
        {
                $user['status'] = true; 
                $user['message'] = 'Successfully logged in!';                            
                $this->set_response($user, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); 
        }
        else
        {

            $this->set_response(array(
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'Login information is not valid!'
            ), REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); 

        }
    }/*if($uname!=''  && $user_type!='')//&& $password!='' */
    else{
        $this->set_response(array(
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'UserName and UserType mandatory'
            ), REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); 
    }

}/// login verification
```

and request is :
http://domain_name/api/controllername/loginverification?username=u_name&password=y#w6737@$%&^%&user_type=abcd

I can not make any change in request.

Comment: It might help if you posted the parts of the code related to your issue ... please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added code now. Can u suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

From client end the value should be URL Encoded
Like the following way for android

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples #oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```